# Help to make the following expression with only $Q$ and $r$

Tags: calculus, physics, integration-by-parts

In a physics book it is said that we can reduce the following expression with only $Q$ and $r$ like $Qr$ or $\dfrac{dQ}{dr}$ or something like that ..... so that it gets vanished after closed integration:

$$\int r\dfrac{d^{2}Q}{dsds'}ds'$$

[image]

It should be possible with integration by parts or with some other techniques.

> My try:
>
> I tried with integration by parts to get:
> $$r\dfrac{dQ}{ds}-\int\dfrac{dr}{ds'}\dfrac{dQ}{ds}ds'$$

I can't get any further. Please help.

> Edit:
>
> It is a well known fact that any value of $Q$ is valid as far we are considering closed circuits because it gets cancelled out after closed integration. You can see it on Wikipedia$-$Ampere Force Law$−$[Historical Background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_force_law#Historical_background)

Comment: I think the text doesn't say that. $Q$ is function of $r$ and doesn't vanish except when constant or zero. From here, Ampere supposed it's constant or zero.

Comment: The page which I posted does say $Q$ is a function of $r$. It is a well known fact that any value of $Q$ is valid as far we are considering closed circuits because it gets cancelled out after closed integration. You can see it on Wikipedia$-$Ampere Force Law$-$[Historical Background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_force_law#Historical_background)

Comment: I see. In your integral, the first term vanish because the evaluation limits are the same (a loop).

Comment: Correct. And for the evaluation limits to be same after closed integration, it needs to be a function of $r$. How can the above term (in question) be a function of $r$ only when integrated w.r.t. $s'$. This is what I am looking for?